# Why was this answer converted to a comment?

Tags: discussion

I added an answer to a question yesterday which has since been converted to a comment, but to me the answer was perfectly valid and didn't need to just be a comment.

[Magento CE 1.9.0.0 downloadable product does not open uploader](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40860/magento-ce-1-9-0-0-downloadable-product-does-not-open-uploader)

The error message posted, though not in English clearly refers to Adobe Flash, and hence my answer was for the user to check they had flash installed and it was up to date.  For whatever reason Marius considered this not to be a valid answer, but why?  It feels like rather heavy handed moderation...

Answer (score 1):

Because you've wrote it in the form of question. For me it looked like clarification request.

I just have undeleted, edited your answer and cleaned up comments.

Comment: Ok thanks for that.